# Automatic `$schema` support in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to describe this JSON:

```
{
  "key1": {},
  "key2": {}
}
```

so I created this JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    ".+": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I add a `$schema` link to the JSON, it's not valid:

[image: JSON schema error]

First, it seems strange that `$schema` would need any kind of special treatment but even if I try this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$schema": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "patternProperties": {
    ".+": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

it's not fixed:

[image: err]

I'm browsing a couple of schemas at http://schemastore.org/json/ and they don't seem to have any special treatment of `$schema`. How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $schema keyword is used to declare that a JSON fragment is actually a piece of JSON Schema. 
But it's not used in your JSON when it's not a schema, i.e. it is not used in your JSON data.

You then use a validator to match the schema against the JSON data. For exmple you can use [this validator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/). In the left you specify the schema in the right you specify JSON data (without any reference or link to the schema, you don't use the $schema keyword in the right side)

The $schema keyword specifies which version of the JSON Schema standard the schema applies to (again the JSON schema, not the JSON data). Most of the time is:

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
```

More info [here](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/schema.html)

Comment: Interesting, so is this method used by VSCode non-standard? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_mapping-in-the-json

Comment: it seems so yes

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, but here is the workaround you need.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$schema": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "object"
  }
}
```

`additionalProperites` applies only to properties that are defined in `properties`.  `patternProperties`, on the other hand, applies to any property that it matches.  The way you wrote it with `patternProperties` means that "$schema" must be a string *and* it must be an object.  Since those two things can never both be true, "$schema" will never validate with any value.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful. The bottom line is that I don't really think adding `$schema` to the JSON itself is correct, it might also influence the runtime behavior which I didn't think of before so I've found other ways to map schema to JSON in VSCode and opened this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26407

Comment: It's only incorrect if you treat it as a built in keyword rather than part of your data model.  It's certainly not a bad thing for a document to be self describing.  VSCode made up a way to do that and that's ok as long as they aren't imposing that decision programmers.  I'm assuming that's not the case since you said you found a workaround that you are comfortable with.